# In $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, prove that the set of rationals is not compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, prove the set of rationals is not compact.

Here is my attempt at a proof by contradiction. If $\mathbb Q$ is compact, then $\forall \{G_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha}$ open covers of $\mathbb Q$, $\exists \alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_n:\mathbb Q \subset G_{\alpha_1} \cup G_{\alpha_2} \cup \cdots \cup G_{\alpha_n}$.

Consider $G_q = (-q,q)$ where $q \in \mathbb Q$. So $\mathbb Q \subset G_{\alpha_1} \cup G_{\alpha_2} \cup \cdots \cup G_{\alpha_n}$.

However, $\mathbb Q \supset (-q-1,q+1) = G_{\alpha_m}, $ so $\mathbb Q \supset G_{\alpha_1} \cup G_{\alpha_2} \cup \cdots \cup G_{\alpha_n} \cup G_{\alpha_m}$.

This is a contradiction $\rightarrow\leftarrow$.

Comment: Note that all the current answers are using Heine-Borel.

Comment: Thanks,Nameless! That theorem has not yet been taught in our class, so we are restricted from using it.\

Answer (score 3):

Compacts are closed, and $\Bbb Q$ certainly is not closed because it is a proper dense subset.

Answer (score 3):

Choose your favorite irrational number.  I'll use $\pi$.  Define $U_n=(-\infty,\pi-\frac1n)\cup (\pi+\frac1n,\infty)$.  The union of these open sets is $\mathbb{R}-\{\pi\}$. And hence certainly is an open cover for the rationals.  However, any nonempty finite subcollection will have a union equal to $U_N$ for some integer $N$, and hence will not cover the rationals.

Answer (score 2):

It is OK, as you are showing, that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not bounded. However, it would be difficult to use this argument for $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$, which is not compact in $[0,1]$. Hence the proof, showing that it is not closed will be more general. (And simple: take an irrational number and a monotone sequence of rationals tending to it on ${\mathbb{R}}$).

Comment: Hmm, I do not see why it would be difficult to show on that closed interval. Could elaborate please?

Comment: @Aida From this comment I can see, that you WILL NOT have difficulties. :-) (Indeed, as finite covering there remains an open interval contained in $[0,1]$, which cannot cover it.) *Should I remove my answer?*

Comment: No, please leave it! I benefit from all contributions here at this site!